# How to share phone contacts in xmpp smack?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am developing chat application using xmpp smack my problem is how to send phone contact information to another users.I am struct here can any body help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can just send a message stanza containing that contact info. AFAIK there is not any particular XEP present for contact sharing.

Answer (score 0):

A phone contact specification is not currently available in XMPP.  Your best bet would be to send the phone contact information in a standard message.

Consider putting some special tokens in place if you want to process these information in a different way than a standard message.